# How can I see dates plot3D in R instead of 5 - digit integers

Tags: r, rgl, plot3d

I make 3d plots in R-studio using `library(rgl)` package. Almost all looks good as shown in the image

[image]

except dates format. Whatever I tried to do, it does not display dates in place of integers. Here is the code I used to generate the plots:

```
 # Plot
Date <- as.Date(df$Date)

df["Color"] <- NA 
mycolors <- c('royalblue')
df$Color <- mycolors

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot3d(
  x = Date, y = C, z = L,
  col = df$Color,
  type = 'p',
  size = 2,
  xlab="Date", ylab="C", zlab="L")
filename <- writeWebGL(dir = file.path(folder, coln),
                       width=600, height=600, reuse = TRUE)
```

I have tried a few things to get the dates on the axis such as:

```
Date1 = as.character(df$Date)
Date = as.Date(Date1, format = "%Y%m%d")
Date = format(as.Date(df$Date, origin="1970-01-01"))
Date <- seq(as.Date("2016-02-29", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), by ="days", length = length(df$Date), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

But nothing works. I get integers all the time which do represent dates, e.g.

> as.Date(17000, "1970-01-01")
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cfdb.png) "2016-07-18"

Can anyone have any ideas how to fix this problem? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: @Ben, I looked but it did not help me For example, the simplest of these answers, anytime(), gave also integers but huge such as 1.6e+09, probably seconds. Furthermore, I did not have this problem with 2D plots, plot(), ggplot2(),

Comment: Can you provide an example data to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rgl` package doesn't use the same formatting functions as base graphics, so you need to format the values yourself.  For example,

```r
df <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2016-02-29"), as.Date("2019-01-01"), length=100),
                 y = rnorm(100),
                 z = rnorm(100))
library(rgl)
plot3d(df, axes = FALSE)
ticks <- pretty(df$Date, 3)
labels <- format(ticks, format = "%Y-%m")
axis3d("x", at = ticks, labels = labels) # Custom on x axis
axes3d(c("y", "z"))                      # Defaults on other axes 
box3d()
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[image: screenshot]

The result of `pretty()` can extend beyond the range of the data, so you might want to reduce it, or change your `xlim` to avoid an axis extending out of range as in this picture for `2016-01`.